# For Loop in Parallel task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I was using Parallel.For  making dummy data

```
List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();
        Parallel.For(0, 100000, i => {
            emp.Add(new Employee() { Id = i.ToString(), name = "EmployeeName "+ i });
        });

        Console.WriteLine("List Full");

        return emp;
```

so , During debugging, i observe different value of emp.Count
for reference please see below

[image: First time]

[image]

Why is this behaving like this - not showing 100000?

Comment: And...? What is your question?

Comment: welcome to the world of synchronisation....

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread safe... You'd be probably better off using PLINQ for such task.

Comment: Sorry forget to mention :: why this is  behaving like this

Comment: I guess the question is why he is not getting 100000 at the end of the method!!

Comment: I guess the question is why should I not do parallel programming on one resource

Comment: @@NEEL :: yes why not 100000

Comment: You're lucky it doesn't blow up. As an aside, try the simpler: `int counter = 0; Parallel.For(0, 100000, dummy => counter++);
Console.WriteLine(counter);`

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get exceptions using a collection that isn't thread safe in a multi threaded domain as such... You should be synchronizing the list access or even better use a concurrent collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is behaving this way is that List is not thread-safe. Two concurrently running threads are adding an object to the list and sometimes there will be a race condition and only one thread is successful, while the other thread only thinks it is successful, or it could blow up and throw an exception if things went really badly for it.

Use one of the Concurrent collections to add things in a concurrency safe way, e.g. A `ConcurrentBag`

I have an example on my blog here:
http://colinmackay.co.uk/2011/04/21/parallelisation-talk-example-concurrentbag/

Do remember that because you are using a concurrent collection and there are multiple threads populating it that you have no control over the sequence, hence it is a `ConcurrentBag` that you would use and not a List (list is ordered). If sequence is important, then you can use Linq at the end to order it the way you want it, you can also use `ToList<T>` to get it into a list, if that is also important.

I've also written a few other articles on concurrency which you might also find useful: http://colinmackay.co.uk/tag/parallelisation/